# ASP Core Cannot Set User Secrets in VS 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

With visual studio 2017, when I try to set a user secret I get the following error:

```
> dotnet user-secrets set Authentication:Google:ClientId mysecretclientid
> Could not find the global property 'UserSecretsId' in MSBuild project 'c:\test\myproj.csproj'. Ensure this property is set in the project or use the '--id' command line option.
```

I have this in my Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: UserSecretsId("project-8084c8e7-0000-0000-b266-b33f42dd88c0")]

...

builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
```

If I add this to my csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UserSecretsId>project-8084c8e7-0000-0000-b266-b33f42dd88c0</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I get an error saying

```
Duplicate 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.UserSecretsIdAttribute'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this link if you havnt yet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets

Comment: Does that mean that you no longer need the UserSecretsId assembly attribute?

Comment: I found this link more helpful and less config: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2017/09/10/managing-secrets-in-net-core-2-0-apps/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I got it working, looks like in VS 2017 you should remove the "`[assembly: UserSecretsId("project-8084c8e7-0000-0000-b266-b33f42dd88c0")]`" attribute and have the following in the csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UserSecretsId>project-8084c8e7-0000-0000-b266-b33f42dd88c0</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: The 'project' prefix is not required. Just head over to a site like (https://guidgenerator.com) and generate a new `GUID`.

Answer (score 76):

In VS Code 2019, you can use the command below to generate the UserSecret section within your csproj file. Please make sure you are within the directory containing the desired csproj file when running the command.

```
dotnet user-secrets init
```

Comment: Try this , somehow it WORKS perfectly!!!

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error and I fixed it by generating a new UserSecretsId.

The UserSecretsId will be generated automatically if you right click on the Project in the Solution Explorer and press `Manage User Secrets`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using external caching provider such as redis put this in your .csproj file
`<PropertyGroup><UserSecretsId>Redistest</UserSecretsId></PropertyGroup>`
Redistest is secret name. It could be anything.